# Macro in Excel to Fit Image in Cell through Browsing

Tags: excel, vba, insert, cell

A macro us needed that will be assigned to a button. Upon clicking, browser should open to lead to the image file.

Once located, the image need be fitted inside Excel Cell, with maintaining its aspect ratio but not exceeding cell size.

For the said need, i have the following two codes that are mutually exclusive. That is, I cannot run them together to fulfill the above need.

First part

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 191.25, 74.25, 49.5 _
    , 16.5).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .PresetTextured msoTexturePapyrus
    .TextureTile = msoTrue
    .TextureOffsetX = 0
    .TextureOffsetY = 0
    .TextureHorizontalScale = 1
    .TextureVerticalScale = 1
    .TextureAlignment = msoTextureTopLeft
End With
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .UserPicture "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
    .TextureTile = msoFalse
End With
```

Second part

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:= _
    "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
Range("C14").Select
```

Best regards
Rehan

Comment: 3rd time of posting, see the second: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68426034/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike 
In my comments I had already informed you that the post is locked for answering and it only allowed to make a new one. Now here is another futile objection on re-posting

Comment: `That is, I cannot run them together to fulfill the above need.` Then merge them and then show us your attempt so that we can help you in achieving what you want?

Comment: Why can't you run them together?

Comment: Simply because I don’t know how to merge. Or where to place the second part inside the first part

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the answer that works...

```
Sub Oval1_Click()
Dim my_file As String
my_file = Application.GetOpenFilename()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 96, 44.25, 279.75, _
        16.5).Select
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture _
        my_file
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .RotateWithObject = msoTrue
    End With
```